# Why specifically say the Beis HaMikdash will return "to its place"?

Tags: tefilla, sefirat-ha-omer, temple-service-avoda

The HaRachaman included in [many Siddurim](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Maariv%2C_Sefirat_HaOmer.55?vhe=The_Metsudah_siddur,_1981&lang=bi) after Sefiras HaOmer says:

> הָרַחֲמָן הוּא יַחֲזִיר לָנוּ עֲבוֹדַת בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ **לִמְקוֹמָה**
> בִּמְהֵרָה בְּיָמֵֽינוּ אָמֵן סֶֽלָה -  The Merciful One, may He return
> for us the service of the Beis Hamikdash **in its place** speedily in our
> days, Amein, Selah.

Why do we specifically ask to return the Avodas Beis Hamikdash "to its place"? Isn't that the *only* place it can take place?

Comment: The Rambam uses similar language to identify Moshiach: ואם יעמוד מלך מבית דוד... ובנה מקדש במקומו

Comment: Perhaps because the temple of chonyo was still in existence at the time of destruction so they instituted the prayer for it to be returned to its proper place

Comment: Yes, that is the only location for the Beis HaMikdash. The Torah repeatedly refers to the "מקום אשר יבחר" (e.g., [D'varim 12:5-18](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0512.htm#5)) as the site of the permanent Beis HaMikdash that would later be identified, and which was identified in Y'rushalayim in the time of David (see also [Rambam, Hil. Beis Hab'chira 2:1-4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007195/jewish/Beit-Habechirah-Chapter-2.htm)).

Comment: Another thing I’ve seen about this is that our prayers today are in the place of the temple service. So while we say the Omer now, we pray that this service that we are doing here, should be returned to its proper place.